# Output: A table of the numbers from 15 to 25 and their squares and cubes, using alert

Tags: javascript, html

im new to javascript and i was wondering how i would do this question. Been having issues and its been really frustrating :(.

I've got this so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head> 
<title> Lab 4 - Task 2.1</title>

<script type = "text/javaScript">

function numbers()
{

var numbers = new Array();
    numbers[0] =  "15";
    numbers[1] =  "16";
    numbers[2] =  "17";
    numbers[3] =  "18";
    numbers[4] =  "19";
    numbers[5] =  "20";
    numbers[6] =  "21";
    numbers[7] =  "22";
    numbers[8] =  "23";
    numbers[9] =  "24";
    numbers[10] =  "25";

alert(numbers)

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="numbers()" value="Show alert box" />

</body>
</html>
```

How will i make this in to a table? As well as fulfill the other tasks it asks for?

Comment: The alert displays the numbers but how do i get the table to display?

Comment: Hey, you seem to be new to programming and this is clearly for homework, so the best I can do is point you in some directions.

What I can tell you is that an Alert dialog cannot use html elements.

Comment: Does your assignment require the output to be in Alert() or can you insert the output into the page itself?

Comment: Hint:  You will need a table element.  Google: html table

Comment: Thanks for the response it requires the output to be an Alert()

Comment: In that case you are going to have to do some fancy footwork with control characters in javascript to format things nicely. \r\n will give you a newline. Furthermore I would seriously recommend doing this in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can append it to the page, you can use this:

```
function addTable() {
    var table = document.createElement("table"),
        row, cell, i;

    table.id = "results_table";

    for (i = 15; i < 26; i++) {
        row = table.insertRow(-1);

        cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = i;

        cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = i*i;

        cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = i*i*i;
    }

    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    if (results.firstChild) {
        results.removeChild(results.firstChild);
    }
    results.appendChild(table);
}
```

with HTML like this:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

If you have to `alert` it as a "table", then you can use this:

```
function alertTable() {
    var ret = "";
    for (var i = 15; i < 26; i++) {
        ret += i + "  " + i*i + "  " + i*i*i + "\n";
    }
    alert(ret);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wazdd/